# htaccess GET query conflict

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wildcard subdomain setup on server to get subdomain as a variable. which works perfectly for the root directory. Now, I have a subdirectory where I need the same it also works. But the problem arises when I append query string to that subdomain. My `.htaccess` in subdirectory example.com/student :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]example.com$
RewriteRule ^MyCourse.php$ MyCourse.php?pageDetailId=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]example.com$
RewriteRule ^MyExam.php?courseId=(0-9+)$ MyExam.php?pageDetailId=%1&courseId=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

MyCourse.php works fine course I dont append any query string to it but MyExam.php needs a GET query string compulsory as courseId. So, whatever I do, either I get the subdomain (pageDetailId) or the courseId but never the both. Also if there is a generic way to get the subdomain variable in all of the files of the subdirectory I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this part of the rule, just add the `QSA flag` and it will send the `query string` if one exists. You don't have to add it to the rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]example.com$
RewriteRule ^MyExam.php$ MyExam.php?pageDetailId=%1 [QSA,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa